# NullPointerException when adding a TabListener

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I get this error message in LogCat:

> 06-25 15:17:34.495: E/AndroidRuntime(5891):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}:
>   **java.lang.NullPointerException**
>   06-25 16:07:43.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6587): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-25 16:07:43.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6587): **at com.example.MyTabsListener.onTabSelected(MyTabListener.java:28)**

This is my main activity:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
        SherlockFragment fragment1 = new AFragment();

        tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1, this
            .getApplicationContext()));
        actionbar.addTab(tab1);
    }

}
```

And my simple TabListener:

```
package com.example;    

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.Toast;  

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public SherlockFragment fragment;
    private final Context appContext;

    public MyTabsListener(SherlockFragment fragment, Context ctx) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.appContext = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(this.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

And finally my class *Fragment A*:

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class AFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekdays, container, false);
    }

}
```

So this function is causing the error in the TabListener:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. MainActivity has to extend `SherlockFragmentActivity` (credits to JosipPranjic!).
2. The *NullPointerException* can be fixed with following code from this SO question: [Null FragmentTransaction being passed to TabListener.onTabSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645549/null-fragmenttransaction-being-passed-to-tablistener-ontabselected)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ignoredFt) {
     FragmentManager fragMgr = ((FragmentActivity) mActivity)
           .getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

     // Check if the fragment is already initialized
     if (mFragment == null) {
         // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
         mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());

         ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
     } else {
         // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
         ft.attach(mFragment);
     }

     ft.commit();
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ignoredFt) {
     FragmentManager fragMgr = ((FragmentActivity) mActivity)
             .getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

     // Check if the fragment is already initialized
     if (mFragment == null) {
         // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
         mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());

         ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
     } else {
         // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
         ft.detach(mFragment);
     }

     ft.commit();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem you have and I think I solved it.

Basically, your **MainActivity** should extend **SherlockFragmentActivity** and NOT **SherlockActivity**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks appContext is not initialized in the code ...... Please initialize that...

Used in `MyTabsListener`

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But if possible pass it in constructor of MyTabsListener and not make that static

```
new MyTabsListener(fragment1,this)
```

Comment: I modified the code according to your answer. But I'm still getting the error, see the edited answer. The error is coming from `onTabSelected()`.

Answer (score 0):

`appContext` is not initialized.
Note that class `Activity` extends class `Context`, and so, to show a `Toast`, it would be enough to

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Another issue: if you want to use the real application context, try `getApplicationContext()`. This will return the singleton application context. More info on this: [link](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)

Comment: I updated the answer few minutes ago. I now pass the app's context via the constructor to my TabListener. But thanks for the link, I could implement some settings-related methods in the singleton.

Comment: Note that what you pass to the `TabListener`, is not the application context, but the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to `this.getApplicationContext()`. But the error in `onTabSelected()` still remains. I think it has something to do with Sherlock.

Comment: As a remark, I would make the `MainActivity` class implement `ActionBar.TabListener`, and in this manner, the listener would have direct access to the activity (which would be `this` in our case).

Comment: But how do I access the current *fragment* then?

Comment: You make a class attribute of the fragment instead of a local variable in method `onCreate()`

Comment: Sorry, I have cut the code posted above. I have more than one tab/fragment.